# How to convert string to json in golang?

Tags: json, string, go

I want to convert the string to Json and give it a return value.

The `c.JSON(200, string(body))` values received via the POST request(writePost) are:

> "{\"message\":{\"@type\":\"response\",\"@service\":\"service.community.cafe\",\"@version\":\"1.0.0\",\"status\":\"200\",\"result\":{\"msg\":\"Success\",\"url\":\"aaabcd\",\"articleId\":211,\"articleUrl\":\"https://abcde.com/abc/211\"}}}"

```golang
// WriteResult Struct
type WriteResult struct {
    Message    int    `form:"msg" json:"msg"`
    URL        string `form:"url" json:"url"`
    ArticleID  int    `form:"articleId" json:"articleId"`
    ArticleURL string `form:"articleUrl" json:"articleUrl"`
}

func writePost(c *gin.Context) {
    var writeInfo WriteInfo

    if err := c.ShouldBind(&writeInfo); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error : ", err)
    }

    url := "https://openapi.abcde.com/articles"

    var bearer = "Bearer " + writeInfo.AccessToken
    var bufs bytes.Buffer

    form := url.Values{}
    form.Add("subject", subject)
    form.Add("content", content)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))

    req.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    writeResult := new(WriteResult)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    c.JSON(200, string(body))
}
```

Is there a way to convert to Json and return it?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying that your string, `body`, is already JSON, and you want to serve it to the client as such?

Comment: @Flimzy I already have Json, but I did not understand it. I have solved it now. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: If you don't understand it, how do you know if you solved it? The accepted answer looks wrong to me, based on your question. I expect you haven't actually solved it.

Comment: @Flimzy I got the method from the answer below.  '''var raw map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(body, &raw)''' I used this code.

Comment: Yeah, that's not correct. That's simply going to double-encode your already encoded string. That will make your code execute, but it won't behave properly. This is why it's important to actually understand what you're doing. "Copy and paste from stackoverflow" is mocked for a reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward in Go

```
out, _ := json.Marshal(body)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40429627/4185234) answer.

Comment: Thank you. However, the resulting values are: "ImV5SnRaWE56WVdkbElqcDdJa0IwZVhCbElqb2ljbVZ6Y0c5dWMyVWlMQ0pBYzJWeWRtbGpaU0k2SW10dmNtVmhMbTVoZG1WeWEyOXlaV0Z6WlhKMmFXTmxMbU52YlcxMWJtbDBlUzVqWVdabElpd2lRSFpsY25OcGIyNGlPaUl4TGpBdU1DSXNJbk4wWVhSMWN5STZJakl3TUNJc0luSmxjM1ZzZENJNmV5SnRjMmNpT2lKVGRXTmpaWE56SWl3aVkyRm1aVlZ5YkNJNkluQnNZWGxyWVc1bklpd2lZWEowYVdOc1pVbGtJam95TWpNc0ltRnlkR2xqYkdWVmNtd2lPaUpvZEhSd2N6b3ZMMk5oWm1VdWJtRjJaWEl1WTI5dEwzQnNZWGxyWVc1bkx6SXlNeUo5ZlgwPSI="

Comment: Here is what I see when I decode it twice: 

{"message":{"@type":"response","@service":"korea.naverkoreaservice.community.cafe","@version":"1.0.0","status":"200","result":{"msg":"Success","cafeUrl":"playkang","articleId":223,"articleUrl":"https://cafe.naver.com/playkang/223"}}}

Comment: I did not know how to use it. Your answer has been a great help. Thank you very much.